# What are the best practices to use iText with Java to avoid memory leaks and unnecessary memory consumption while printing and merging pdf files

Tags: memory-management, out-of-memory, itext, heap-memory

I am using iText 2.1.7 library to create pdf reports. There is only two small logs involved in all pages as an image content. Rest is all textual and tabular content. I have made the images singleton to avoid extra memory use for images. This seems to be working fine up to 10000 records. But beyond that the heap is running out of space. Currently heap size is set to 1Gb.

Is there any other optimizations that I can do to reduce memory consumptions while performing pdf generation?

update 1: adding more details and code.

My requirement is to print individual pdf file for each of the record and merge them together into a single pdf file as the final output. To reduce memory usage i am loading data as batches and performing print + merge before loading the next batch. The methods I use are given below:

```
    // This method is used to print seperate pdf files for each record to be printed. Each record prints a seperate pdf file with 1 to 4 pages containing tabular data.
        public byte[] print(PrintData printData) throws Exception
        {
                ByetArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByetArrayOutputStream();
                // create a document
                Document document = new Document()
                // create the writer
                pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
                // open the document
                document.open();
                // build the page
                addPdfContents(document, printData);
                // close the document
                document.close();
                pdfWriter.close();
                byte[] printFile = outputStream.toByteArray();
                outputStream.close();
                return printFile;
         }

//the final document and output stream are defined outside as class variables. which will be closed after the final merge operation.

   PdfCopy copier = null;
   ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = null;

   public void initializeFinalDoc(){
        outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Ddocument document = new Document();
        copier = new PdfCopy(document, outputStream);
        document.open();
   }

    public byte[] getFinalDoc(){
        document.close();
        outputStream.close();
        return outputStream.toByteArray();
    }
// After printing individual files it is merged with the master document to get the final output as a single merged document.
    public void merge(byte[] eachFile) throws Exception
    { 
            if(eachFile != null)
            {
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(eachFile);
                PdfImportedPage page;
                int numberOfPages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
                for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPages;)
                {
                    ++i;
                    page = pdfCopier.getImportedPage(reader, i);
                    pdfCopier.addPage(page);
                }
                pdfCopier.freeReader(reader);
            }
        }
```

I am not adding all content into a table. 
It seems the pdf file size is increasing after merging with the final document. When I printed 5000 records, there were 5000 pages and almost 400Mb size for the final pdf file. Any idea why the size of the file is going high? Is there anything wrong in the approach i am following?

update 2: I have updated the sample code. Please excuse the previous mistakes.

Comment: Show us some code, just a simplified overview. 10000 records is nothing, you must be doing something wrong.

Comment: *iText 2.1.7* is ancient and many bugs have been fixed since then. As far as I know, though  even that old state could easily produce PDFs of many times 10000 pages. Thus, as @PauloSoares indicates, more details about the code are required. I hope you do not use one big table containing all content.

Comment: After your edit: I don't see you instantiating the `outputStream` in `merge`. Is it merely missing in your code here or do you actually re-use the same `ByteArrayOutputStream` instance again and again in that method? In that case please be aware that `ByteArrayOutputStream.close` is a no-operation method and multiple calls of `merge` result in a giant backing `byte[]`.

Comment: After your next edit: Ok, so it's not a wrong `ByteArrayOutputStream` use... hhmmmm. I see you freeing the `reader` resources from the `pdfCopier` but I don't see you closing the `reader` thereafter. Have you tried that?

Comment: I tried closing the reader after the merging the file. But that did not give any improvements.

Comment: @mkl Instead of using `PdfCopy` I tried using `PdfSmartCopy` which seems to be helping a lot in reducing the final printout size as well as printing more number of records. I have tested the it with upto 45000 records, which gives one pdf file of 45000 pages. And the surprisingly, the file size reduced to 140mb. :-O ... Do you see any issues in using `PdfSmartCopy` in my code? Could you please tell me how does it make this difference?

Comment: `PdfSmartCopy` attempts to *not* add the same object twice to the result but instead re-use the copy added first. If you e.g. happen to have the identical image on each page, the smart variant adds it only once while the dumb one adds it thousands of times.

Comment: Alright. That explains the growing memory issue. In my case there was the same logo being printed in all pages. `PdfSmartCopy` seems to be working smart..

Comment: However do you see any issues with using `PdfSmartCopy` ?

Comment: @pathe.kiran The question is a bout iText 2.1.7. You try to hijack it for requesting a *solution for latest iText 7 version.* Please don't. Instead ask a new question. Furthermore, what is "1 Lakh"? Sounds like a local unit somewhere...

Comment: Furthermore, the original question is about *merging files* while you are asking about *creating PDFs*. Thus, your bounty does not make sense here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am mentioning here the changes I did as per the discussions in the comments area. So that this question can be closed and will be helpful for someone else.

1. Close all the resources in the code, while printing and merging the contents and make the unused references available for garbage collector.
2. Instead of using `PdfCopy` try using `PdfSmartCopy` if the content has repeating images.

> PdfSmartCopy attempts to not add the same object twice to the result but instead re-use the copy added first.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am looking for solution with iText latest version (v7) . PdfSmartCopy  is available in 5.5.9 version.